Why can't normal be drawn to circle from internal point?
By definition normal is a line perpendicular to the curve at the point of their contact and a line isn't limited to the external of a circle it will continue to its inside and thus there will be points on the normal line that will lie on the inside of the circle.
So that should mean that taking a inside point we can make a line passing through it and cutting the circle perpendicularly.
Please let me know if I'm interpreting normal wrongly and what exactly it is by standard definition

Your logic has problems: Your arguments does not claim that any point inside is hit by a normal from the outside (I don't think that can happen for any closed curve, but proving that is left as an exercise), and without that argument you have points that you can't make a line through that is perpendicular to the circle.

But as my parenthesis implies: I think you can draw a normal to a circle through any internal point, why do you think you can't?

Maybe there is an understanding of “line” here? Maybe you should replace line with vector, say of a given size (so has finite length and direction) and maybe this will clear up your confusion.

@Henriksupportsthecommunity I have seen that in a couple of places my mathematics professor also believes that to be true

@Benjamin Yes, but that is what I'm trying to know, what exactly is normal by standard definition if its not a line, because if it is a line the it ought to pass through any internal point and thus the possibility of normal being drawn from an internal point

@Unnat I suppose what exactly people will mean in the context. But usually people will mean a vector which is orthogonal to every tangent vector at the point. Often, one will also consider a unit sized normal. Then one will distinguish (when it’s possible to do, eg possible on a sphere but not on a Möbius strip) between outer and inner normals. If you have an outer unit normal, then this will not go “through” any interior points.

Think of it this way: if you want normal lines (and you don’t specify that it is a half line) then you cannot expect interior points to be left “untouched”. If instead you are talking about normal vectors, then these can be taken not to touch the interior points. This is all sort of vague, though because it’s not clear what context we are talking about exactly.
